# todolist software, cannot set due date

Tags: to-do, windows-7

I use todolist 6.0.8 by AbstractSpoon. I am not able to set the due date.

Can you tell me how to set the due date?

I can see the due time. below the tasklist but it is disabled/grey.

Oh I confused it with due time. Due time is disabled but time day is not...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the relevant task. Click on the drop-down button on the due date control and pick the date from the calendar that appears.

The due date control may not be visible if the column has been turned off and you have the preference to only display controls for visible columns turned on.

P.S.: To edit the due date you must have the edit fields visible below the tasklist. It maybe that they are hidden because you have the `View > Maximize tasklists` menu option set.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful, in Todolist 6.7.7 it is not so easy to have the edit fields visible below the tasklist.

If you have the `View > Maximize tasklists` menu option set (little tick), unticking it will not work since it maximizes the comments. In that case you still have to untick `View > Maximize comments`: both options unticked will let you have the edits fields visible.